# How to insert arrays into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I am scraping data and then turning the data into arrays that output as follows:

```
array(8) {   
           [0]=> array(8) {   
                             [1]=> string(1) "1"   
                             [2]=> string(8) "Henricho"   
                             [3]=> string(10) "Bruintjies"   
                             [4]=> string(2) "23"   
                             [5]=> string(3) "Agn"   
                             [6]=> string(6) "10.17A"   
                             [7]=> string(4) "-0.2"   
                             [8]=> string(1) "8" }  
           [1]=> array(8) {   
                             [1]=> string(1) "2"   
                             [2]=> string(5) "Akani"   
                             [3]=> string(7) "Simbine"   
                             [4]=> string(2) "23"   
                             [5]=> string(3) "Agn"   
                             [6]=> string(6) "10.21A"   
                             [7]=> string(4) "-0.2"   
                             [8]=> string(1) "7" }
```

It is displayed by using `var_dump($results);`

Is there a simple way to input the data into a sql table using $results?

Comment: You can create your own class to do that. Simply put, you can run a `foreach` loop over the array and putting data to MySQL.

Comment: You can use nested `foreach` loop to loop over the arrays or array and insert the data into sql table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to you something like:

```
foreach ($results as $value){  
    $allValues = implode('", "', $value); 
    //the above line will give us something like ("1", "Henricho"....etc)
    $query ='Insert into(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8)  
         Values("'.$allValues.'")';
    //You can now execute your query
    echo $query."<BR />";
}
```

[<kbd>**Check Demo Here**</kbd>](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn$results%20=%20array(%5Cn%5Ct%200%20=%3E%20array(%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%201=%3E%20%221%22,%5Cn%202=%3E%20%22Henricho%22,%5Cn%203=%3E%20%22Bruintjies%22,%5Cn%204=%3E%20%2223%22,%5Cn%205=%3E%20%22Agn%22%20,%5Cn%206=%3E%20%2210.17A%22,%5Cn%207=%3E%20%22-0.2%22,%5Cn%208=%3E%20%228%22%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%20),%5Cn%5Ct%201%20=%3E%20array(%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%201=%3E%20%222%22,%5Cn%202=%3E%20%22Akani%22,%5Cn%203=%3E%20%22Simbine%22,%5Cn%204=%3E%20%2223%22%20,%5Cn%205=%3E%20%22Agn%22%20,%5Cn%206=%3E%20%2210.17A%22,%5Cn%207=%3E%20%22-0.2%22%20,%5Cn%208=%3E%20%228%22%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%20)%5Cn%20);%5Cn%5Cnforeach%20($results%20as%20$value)%7B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct$allValues%20=%20implode('%22,%22',%20$value);%5Cn%20//the%20above%20line%20will%20give%20us%20something%20like%20(%221%22,%20%22Henricho%22....etc)%5Cn%20$query%20='Insert%20into(col1,%20col2,%20col3,%20col4,%20col5,%20col6,%20col7,%20col8)%5Cn%20Values(%22'.$allValues.'%22)';%5Cn%20//You%20can%20now%20execute%20your%20query%5Cn%5Ctecho%20$query.%22%3CBR%20/%3E%22;%5Cn%7D%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)

Comment: I have added `include('connect.php');` to link to my database and added the table name + headings: `include('connect.php');

foreach ($results as $value){  
    foreach ($value as $key => $str) 
     {
        //here we remove this 'string(1) ' including the space
        //then put back the value inside the array 
        $value[$key] = trim(substr($str, 10)); 
     }
    $allValues =  implode(",", $values); 
$query ="Insert into 100mMenFinal (Pos, Name, Surname, Age, Team, Perf, Q, Pts)  
             Values($allValues)"    
}` I do however get: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: print your query variable and show me the results `echo $query;`

Comment: Should `echo $query;` go after the last `}`?

Comment: before that, put this `echo $query."< /BR>";` after this `//You can now execute your query`

Comment: Now I get this: `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/productp/public_html/webscraper/live/test.php on line 166
Insert into 100mMenFinal (Pos, Name, Surname, Age, Team, Perf, Q, Pts) Values()< /BR>`

Comment: it was not working because i made typos, the answer was not tested, i tested it now and created a demo, check my edited answer

Comment: Mine show up like this: `Insert into 100mMenFinal('Pos', 'Name', 'Surname', 'Age', 'Team', 'Perf', 'Q', 'Wind', 'Pts', 'ID') Values(,,,,,,,)` and is not inputting into mySQL

Comment: remove the second foreach `foreach ($value as $key => $str) 
     {
        //here we remove this 'string(1) ' including the space
        //then put back the value inside the array 
        $value[$key] = trim(substr($str, 10)); 
     }` and try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120950/discussion-between-seef-and-the-flash).

Answer (score 0):

The data you used var_dump on to give the above result in my guess would be:

```
$result = array(
array("1","Henricho","Bruintjies","23","Agn","10.17A","-0.2","8"),  
array("2","Akani" , "Simbine" ,"23" ,"Agn", "10.21A","-0.2","7" )
);
```

lets assume the fields you want to insert data to are id, firstname, lastname, age, anotherfield,anotherfield,anotherfield,anotherfield

```
foreach ($result AS $innerArray){
// In above $result, each $innerArray is an indexed array
    $sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO `tablename` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `age`, `anotherfield`, `anotherfield`, `anotherfield`, `anotherfield`) VALUES('.implode(",", $innerArray).')';
// You can now execute your sql query depending on the mysql adapter you are using.

}
```